# terraform error parsing tfvars file when using the -var-file flag

Tags: terraform

I'm having trouble trying to execute any terraform command (i.e. validate, plan, apply) when I provide a -var-file flag. 
for example:
`terraform plan -var-file=./Dev/common.tfvars`

I then receive the following error:

> invalid value "./Dev/common.tfvars" for flag -var-file: Error parsing ./Dev/common.tfvars: At 1:1: illegal char

content of common.tfvars:

```
environment = "dev"
project-name = "project-name-here"
```

content of variables.tf:

```
variable "environment" {
  type = "string",
  default = "dev"
}

variable "location-lookup" {
  type = "map",
  default = {
    australiaeast       = "AUEA",
    australiasoutheast  = "AUSE",
    uksouth             = "UKSO",
    ukwest              = "UKWE",
    westeurope          = "EUWE"
  }
}

variable "project-name" {
  type = "string"
}
```

Supplying the `project-name` using the var flag works without issue, so I suspect I'm missing something in the common.tfvars file.

Comment: Try this: `terraform plan -var-file="Dev/common.tfvars"`. Disclaimer: I'm not as familiar with TF on Windows, so I'm not 100% sure this will work, but worth the 5 secs to try it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen if your *common.tfvars* is UTF-8 encoded with BOM. Try re-encoding your vars file without BOM.